# Scheduled adjustable payments

Tags: c#, finance

**Short Description:**

I'm working on a "small" project for our finance department. The problem I'm having is managing this large function (*at the bottom*). It's so large because I'm having troubles reducing the function into smaller parts without either having to pass many parameters along or recalculate some things. Any times or suggestions in accomplishing this? (I've been trying to avoid any functions with more than 3 parameters, hopefully this isn't too irrational a desire).

**Entity Details**

- The header is simply put, the initial loan. When this is created so are all of its schedules (individual payments for a specific date).
- Adjustments can be done changing the PaymentAmount, GoalAmount (effectively the RemainingBalance), and DecreaseAmountBy (Amount to decrease payment amount after each payment).
- Schedules need to be created ahead of time for various reasons.
- Adjustments have AdjustmentType. The three valid adjustment types are "Adjustment", "Replacement", and "Zero".
- An "Adjustment" is just a changing of existing schedules.
- "Replacements" can be extensions or compression (add/remove schedules).
- "Zero" is just an adjustment where PaymentAmount, DecreaseAmountBy, and RemainingBalance is set to 0 for the remainder of the existing schedules.

**RecurringHeader:**

```
// Represents an initial loan that needs to be repaid.
public partial class RecurringHeader
{     
    // Completely irrelevant properties removed.  
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public long PaymentAccountID { get; set; }
    public string NoteNbr { get; set; }
    public string TransactionType { get; set; }
    public string AcctCode { get; set; }
    public decimal PaymentAmount { get; set; }
    public int PostingKey2 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> DecreaseAmountBy { get; set; }
    public bool IsUnlimited { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> NbrOfOccurrences { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> GoalAmount { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime EffectiveOnWeekEndingDate { get; set; }
}
```

**Adjustment:**

```
// Represents a change to the payment plan for a loan.
public partial class RecurringCustomerAdjustment
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public long RecurringHeaderID { get; set; }
    public string AdjustmentType { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> MonthlyPaymentAmount { get; set; }
    public decimal PaymentAmount { get; set; }
    public int PostingKey2 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> DecreaseAmountBy { get; set; }
    public bool IsUnlimited { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> NbrOfOccurrences { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> GoalAmount { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime EffectiveOnWeekEndingDate { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
}
```

**Schedule:**

```
// Represents a single scheduled payment for a loan.
public partial class RecurringSchedule
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public long PaymentAccountID { get; set; }
    public long RecurringHeaderID { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime PaymentDate { get; set; }
    public decimal PaymentAmount { get; set; }
    public int OccurrenceNbr { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> RemainingBalance { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> ModifiedOn { get; set; }
    public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
}
```

**Point of Concern: Adjustments**

My real troubles are applying the adjustments to the existing schedules. I've done it, but it's a very large function that's kind of a mess (imo).

```
/// <summary>
/// Given all of the header's existing schedules will apply the adjustment to them.
/// This works for Adjustments, Replacements, and Zeroes alike.
/// </summary>
public IEnumerable<RecurringSchedule> AdjustSchedules(IEnumerable<RecurringSchedule> allHeaderSchedules)
{
    // DATE-RANGE: Get the effective date ranges for the adjustment.
    DateTime adjEffectiveStart = this.GetEffectiveDate();
    DateTime adjEffectiveEnd = this.GetEffectiveEndingDate();

    // PARTITION: Get all of the existing schedule for the header.
    // 1) Add the unaffected to the list (Before Adjustment).
    // 2) Get a list of schedules whose PaymentAmount & RemainingBalance will be affected (During Adjustment).
    // 3) Get a list of schedules whose RemainingBalance will only be affected (After Adjustment).
    IEnumerable<RecurringSchedule> allSchedules = allHeaderSchedules.OrderBy(x => x.OccurrenceNbr);

    IList<RecurringSchedule> schedules = new List<RecurringSchedule>(allSchedules.Where(x => x.PaymentDate < adjEffectiveStart).OrderBy(x => x.OccurrenceNbr));
    IList<RecurringSchedule> schedulesDuringAdj = allSchedules.Where(x => x.PaymentDate >= adjEffectiveStart && x.PaymentDate < adjEffectiveEnd).OrderBy(x => x.OccurrenceNbr).ToList();
    IList<RecurringSchedule> schedulesAfterAdj = allSchedules.Where(x => x.PaymentDate >= adjEffectiveEnd).OrderBy(x => x.OccurrenceNbr).ToList();

    // REPLACEMENT:
    Int32 occurrenceShift = adjEffectiveStart.Subtract(allSchedules.OrderBy(x => x.OccurrenceNbr).First().PaymentDate).Days / 7;
    RecurringSchedule lastExistingSchedule = schedulesDuringAdj.Last();
    Int32 startingOccurrence = lastExistingSchedule.OccurrenceNbr + 1;
    Int32 endingOccurrence = Math.Max((this.NbrOfOccurrences ?? 0) + occurrenceShift, allHeaderSchedules.Count());

    // SETUP: Determine the initial values for updated schedules.
    Decimal paymentAmount = this.PaymentAmount;
    Decimal decreaseAmountBy = this.DecreaseAmountBy ?? 0;
    Decimal remainingBalance = this.GoalAmount ?? schedules.Last().RemainingBalance.Value;

    // ADJUST: Update each schedule, decrementing remainingBalance and paymentAmount as necessary.
    foreach (RecurringSchedule schedule in schedulesDuringAdj)
    {
        // RemainingBalance is the value AFTER payment amount has been taken out.
        remainingBalance = remainingBalance - paymentAmount > 0 
                            ? remainingBalance - paymentAmount 
                            : 0;

        schedule.PaymentAmount = paymentAmount;
        schedule.RemainingBalance = remainingBalance;

        // Payment Amount is decreased after the payment, if applicable.
        paymentAmount = paymentAmount - decreaseAmountBy > 0
                        ? paymentAmount - decreaseAmountBy
                        : 0;

        if (remainingBalance != 0)
        {
            // THRESHHOLD: If the balance after the next payment is under
            // the threshhold then add it to the current payment and let
            // remaining payment schedules be a payment of nothing.
            if (schedulesAfterAdj.Count == 0 && schedule.AdjustForThreshhold(decreaseAmountBy))
            {
                paymentAmount = 0;
                remainingBalance = 0;
                decreaseAmountBy = 0;
            }
        }

        schedules.Add(schedule);
    }

    // POST-ADJUST: Replacements remove scedules after. i.e. Never add them.
    if (this.AdjustmentType != "Replacement")
    {
        // POST-ADJUST: Those after an adjustment still need their RemainingBalances updated.
        foreach (RecurringSchedule schedule in schedulesAfterAdj)
        {
            remainingBalance -= schedule.PaymentAmount;

            schedule.RemainingBalance = remainingBalance;

            // THRESHHOLD: If the balance after the next payment is under
            // the threshhold then add it to the current payment and let
            // remaining payment schedules be a payment of nothing.
            if (remainingBalance != 0 && schedule.AdjustForThreshhold(decreaseAmountBy))
            {
                paymentAmount = 0;
                remainingBalance = 0;
                decreaseAmountBy = 0;
            }

            schedules.Add(schedule);
        }
    }
    // EXTENSION: Replacements Only.
    else if (this.AdjustmentType == "Replacement" && !schedulesAfterAdj.Any() && endingOccurrence >= startingOccurrence)
    {
        String createdBy = HttpContext.Current != null &&
                            HttpContext.Current.User != null &&
                            HttpContext.Current.User.Identity != null
                            ? HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
                            : "System";

        DateTime startingDate = lastExistingSchedule.PaymentDate.AddDays(7);

        for (int i = startingOccurrence; i <= endingOccurrence; ++i)
        {
            // RemainingBalance is the value AFTER payment amount has been taken out.
            remainingBalance = remainingBalance - paymentAmount > 0 
                                ? remainingBalance - paymentAmount 
                                : 0;

            RecurringSchedule newSchedule = new RecurringSchedule() {
                PaymentAccountID = this.PaymentAccountID,
                RecurringHeaderID = this.RecurringHeaderID,
                PaymentDate = startingDate,
                OccurrenceNbr = i,
                PaymentAmount = paymentAmount,
                RemainingBalance = remainingBalance,
                CreatedBy = createdBy,
                CreatedOn = DateTime.Now
            };

            // Increment the date by a week.
            startingDate = startingDate.AddDays(7);

            // Payment Amount is decreased after the payment, if applicable.
            paymentAmount = paymentAmount - decreaseAmountBy > 0
                            ? paymentAmount - decreaseAmountBy
                            : 0;

            if (remainingBalance != 0)
            {
                // THRESHHOLD: If the balance after the next payment is under
                // the threshhold then add it to the current payment and let
                // remaining payment schedules be a payment of nothing.
                if (schedulesAfterAdj.Count == 0 && newSchedule.AdjustForThreshhold(decreaseAmountBy))
                {
                    paymentAmount = 0;
                    remainingBalance = 0;
                    decreaseAmountBy = 0;
                }
            }

            schedules.Add(newSchedule);
        }
    }

    return schedules;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Considering `allSchedules = allHeaderSchedules.OrderBy(x => x.OccurrenceNbr)`, why then do you do `allSchedules.OrderBy(x => x.OccurrenceNbr)` later on?

---

This method is 140+ lines long, and does a lot. The next person who needs to maintain it will have to spend a lot of time to figure out what it all does, and your idea of splitting the method into smaller, more manageable ones is the right one. My advice: make it a class of its own. That way you can store variables like `schedules`, `schedulesDuringAdj` and `schedulesAfterAdj` at class level, and you don't need to pass them as parameters to other methods:

```
internal class ScheduleAdjuster
{
   private readonly IEnumerable<RecurringSchedule> _allHeaderSchedules;
   priavte readonly IEnumerable<RecurringSchedule> _allSchedules;

   private IList<RecurringSchedule> _schedules;
   // etc.

   public ScheduleAdjuster(IEnumerable<RecurringSchedule> allHeaderSchedules)
   {
      _allHeaderSchedules = allHeaderSchedules;
      _allSchedules = _allHeaderSchedules.OrderBy(x => x.OccurrenceNbr);
      /// etc.
   }

   public IEnumerable<RecurringSchedule> Execute()
   {
      // call various methods 
      // these can use the "global" variables like _allHeaderSchedules and _allSchedules etc.
      // without you needing to pass numerous parameters
   }
}
```

There are a dozen or so places where you use a value from the class that contains `AdjustSchedules`: is it possible to pass this class as a parameter to `ScheduleAdjuster`? Quite frankly I wonder how big that parent class is, considering this single method is 140+ lines long.

---

There are several typos in your comments: `scedules`, `threshhold`.

---

The initial parameter of your method is `IEnumerable<RecurringSchedule> allHeaderSchedules`, which you then enumerate multiple times. [Which isn't a good thing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8240935/648075) ([ReSharper warns about this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20129161/648075)). I'd suggest using an `ICollection<T>` instead.

Comment: I agree. From the looks of it the main issue with the original code is the lackluster object model. Splitting huge multi-purpose entities into smaller classes with fewer responsibilities would be a major imrovement, IMHO.

Answer (score 5):

**Code style**

It isn't easy to follow this code, because you are switching styles a lot, sometimes from one line of code to the other.

> ```
> IList<RecurringSchedule> schedules = new List<RecurringSchedule>(allSchedules.Where(x => x.PaymentDate < adjEffectiveStart).OrderBy(x => x.OccurrenceNbr));
> IList<RecurringSchedule> schedulesDuringAdj = allSchedules.Where(x => x.PaymentDate >= adjEffectiveStart && x.PaymentDate < adjEffectiveEnd).OrderBy(x => x.OccurrenceNbr).ToList();
> ```

- Sometimes you are using `int`, `decimal` and then you are using `Int32` and `Decimal`.
- Sometimes you are checking if the `Count` property of the `IList` `==0` and sometimes you are using `Any()` which by the way for types/interfaces implementing `ICollection<T>`, which `IList<T>` does, will add a little overhead by having a null check on the passed `IEnumerable<TSource>` and a cast to `ICollection<T>` together with a null check.

---

Extracing this `paymentAmount`, `decreaseAmountBy` and `remainingBalance` to a separate class like so

```
public class PaymentParameter
{
    public decimal PaymentAmount { get; set; }
    public decimal DecreaseAmountBy { get; set; }
    public decimal RemainingBalance { get; set; }
}
```

will help to refactor this method.

So let us start by extracting the first loop to a separate method

```
private IList<RecurringSchedule> UpdateSchedules(IList<RecurringSchedule> schedulesDuringAdj, PaymentParameter paymentParameter, bool hasSchedulesAfterAdjustment)
{
    IList<RecurringSchedule> schedules = new List<RecurringSchedule>();
    decimal remainingBalance = paymentParameter.RemainingBalance;
    decimal paymentAmount = paymentParameter.PaymentAmount;
    decimal decreaseAmountBy = paymentParameter.DecreaseAmountBy;

    foreach (RecurringSchedule schedule in schedulesDuringAdj)
    {
        // RemainingBalance is the value AFTER payment amount has been taken out.
        remainingBalance = Math.Max(remainingBalance - paymentAmount, 0);

        schedule.PaymentAmount = paymentAmount;
        schedule.RemainingBalance = remainingBalance;

        // Payment Amount is decreased after the payment, if applicable.
        paymentAmount = Math.Max(paymentAmount - decreaseAmountBy, 0);

        if (remainingBalance != 0)
        {
            // THRESHHOLD: If the balance after the next payment is under
            // the threshhold then add it to the current payment and let
            // remaining payment schedules be a payment of nothing.
            if (hasSchedulesAfterAdjustment && schedule.AdjustForThreshhold(decreaseAmountBy))
            {
                paymentAmount = 0;
                remainingBalance = 0;
                decreaseAmountBy = 0;
            }
        }

        schedules.Add(schedule);
    }

    paymentParameter.DecreaseAmountBy = decreaseAmountBy;
    paymentParameter.PaymentAmount = paymentAmount;
    paymentParameter.RemainingBalance = remainingBalance;

    return schedules;
}
```

As you will see, I have replaced the tenary conditions by simple calls to `Math.Max()`.

The next method to extract is for the case that `this.AdjustmentType != "Replacement"` like so

```
private IList<RecurringSchedule> UpdateNonReplacements(IList<RecurringSchedule> schedulesAfterAdj, PaymentParameter paymentParameter)
{
    IList<RecurringSchedule> schedules = new List<RecurringSchedule>();
    decimal remainingBalance = paymentParameter.RemainingBalance;
    decimal paymentAmount = paymentParameter.PaymentAmount;
    decimal decreaseAmountBy = paymentParameter.DecreaseAmountBy;

    foreach (RecurringSchedule schedule in schedulesAfterAdj)
    {
        remainingBalance -= schedule.PaymentAmount;

        schedule.RemainingBalance = remainingBalance;

        // THRESHHOLD: If the balance after the next payment is under
        // the threshhold then add it to the current payment and let
        // remaining payment schedules be a payment of nothing.
        if (remainingBalance != 0 && schedule.AdjustForThreshhold(decreaseAmountBy))
        {
            paymentAmount = 0;
            remainingBalance = 0;
            decreaseAmountBy = 0;
        }

        schedules.Add(schedule);
    }
    paymentParameter.DecreaseAmountBy = decreaseAmountBy;
    paymentParameter.PaymentAmount = paymentAmount;
    paymentParameter.RemainingBalance = remainingBalance;

    return schedules;
}
```

quite easy, isn't it ?

Because the `else if` targets some more parameters, we will extend the `PaymentParameter` class to take them into account too.

```
public class PaymentParameter
{
    public decimal PaymentAmount { get; set; }
    public decimal DecreaseAmountBy { get; set; }
    public decimal RemainingBalance { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartingDate { get; set; }
    public int StartingOccurance { get; set; }
    public int EndingOccurance { get; set; }
}
```

so we can extract the method as follows

```
private IList<RecurringSchedule> UpdateReplacements(PaymentParameter paymentParameter)
{
    IList<RecurringSchedule> schedules = new List<RecurringSchedule>();

    if (paymentParameter.EndingOccurance < paymentParameter.StartingOccurance)
    {
        return schedules;
    }

    string createdBy = HttpContext.Current != null &&
                            HttpContext.Current.User != null &&
                            HttpContext.Current.User.Identity != null
                            ? HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
                            : "System";

    DateTime startingDate = paymentParameter.StartingDate.AddDays(7);

    decimal remainingBalance = paymentParameter.RemainingBalance;
    decimal paymentAmount = paymentParameter.PaymentAmount;
    decimal decreaseAmountBy = paymentParameter.DecreaseAmountBy;

    for (int i = paymentParameter.StartingOccurance; i <= paymentParameter.EndingOccurance; ++i)
    {
        // RemainingBalance is the value AFTER payment amount has been taken out.
        remainingBalance = Math.Max(remainingBalance - paymentAmount, 0);

        RecurringSchedule newSchedule = new RecurringSchedule()
        {
            PaymentAccountID = this.PaymentAccountID,
            RecurringHeaderID = this.RecurringHeaderID,
            PaymentDate = startingDate,
            OccurrenceNbr = i,
            PaymentAmount = paymentAmount,
            RemainingBalance = remainingBalance,
            CreatedBy = createdBy,
            CreatedOn = DateTime.Now
        };

        // Increment the date by a week.
        startingDate = startingDate.AddDays(7);

        // Payment Amount is decreased after the payment, if applicable.
        paymentAmount = Math.Max(paymentAmount - decreaseAmountBy, 0);

        if (remainingBalance != 0)
        {
            // THRESHHOLD: If the balance after the next payment is under
            // the threshhold then add it to the current payment and let
            // remaining payment schedules be a payment of nothing.
            if (newSchedule.AdjustForThreshhold(decreaseAmountBy))
            {
                paymentAmount = 0;
                remainingBalance = 0;
                decreaseAmountBy = 0;
            }
        }

        schedules.Add(newSchedule);
    }
    return schedules;
}
```

As you maybe have seen, there isn't a check for `schedulesAfterAdj.Count == 0` anymore. This check had been superflous because one of the conditions to enter the `else if` had been `!schedulesAfterAdj.Any()` so it will be entered only if `schedulesAfterAdj.Count == 0`.

The former `AdjustSchedules()` will then look like so

```
public IEnumerable<RecurringSchedule> AdjustSchedules(IEnumerable<RecurringSchedule> allHeaderSchedules)
{
    // DATE-RANGE: Get the effective date ranges for the adjustment.
    DateTime adjEffectiveStart = this.GetEffectiveDate();
    DateTime adjEffectiveEnd = this.GetEffectiveEndingDate();

    // PARTITION: Get all of the existing schedule for the header.
    // 1) Add the unaffected to the list (Before Adjustment).
    // 2) Get a list of schedules whose PaymentAmount & RemainingBalance will be affected (During Adjustment).
    // 3) Get a list of schedules whose RemainingBalance will only be affected (After Adjustment).
    IEnumerable<RecurringSchedule> allSchedules = allHeaderSchedules.OrderBy(x => x.OccurrenceNbr);

    List<RecurringSchedule> schedules = allSchedules.Where(x => x.PaymentDate < adjEffectiveStart).ToList();
    IList<RecurringSchedule> schedulesDuringAdj = allSchedules.Where(x => x.PaymentDate >= adjEffectiveStart && x.PaymentDate < adjEffectiveEnd).ToList();
    IList<RecurringSchedule> schedulesAfterAdj = allSchedules.Where(x => x.PaymentDate >= adjEffectiveEnd).ToList();

    // REPLACEMENT:
    int occurrenceShift = adjEffectiveStart.Subtract(allSchedules.First().PaymentDate).Days / 7;
    RecurringSchedule lastExistingSchedule = schedulesDuringAdj.Last();


    PaymentParameter paymentParameter = new PaymentParameter()
               {
                   PaymentAmount = this.PaymentAmount,
                   DecreaseAmountBy = this.DecreaseAmountBy ?? 0,
                   RemainingBalance = this.GoalAmount ?? schedules.Last().RemainingBalance.Value,
                   StartingDate = lastExistingSchedule.PaymentDate,
                   StartingOccurance = lastExistingSchedule.OccurrenceNbr + 1,
                   EndingOccurance =Math.Max((this.NbrOfOccurrences ?? 0) + occurrenceShift, allHeaderSchedules.Count())
               };

    schedules.AddRange(UpdateSchedules(schedulesDuringAdj, paymentParameter, schedulesAfterAdj.Count == 0));

    // POST-ADJUST: Replacements remove scedules after. i.e. Never add them.
    if (this.AdjustmentType != "Replacement")
    {
        schedules.AddRange(UpdateNonReplacements(schedulesAfterAdj, paymentParameter));
    }
    // EXTENSION: Replacements Only.
    else if (this.AdjustmentType == "Replacement" && !schedulesAfterAdj.Any())
    {
        schedules.AddRange(UpdateReplacements(paymentParameter));
    }

    return schedules;
}
```

As you may noticed I have

- changed the type of `schedules` from `IList<RecurringSchedule>` to `List<RecurringSchedule>` to use the `AddRange()` method.
- removed the checking for `endingOccurance >= startingOccurance` because this is used in the `UpdateReplacements()` method as a guard clause.
- removed the redundant `OrderBy(x => x.OccurrenceNbr)` calls
- changed `Int32` to `int`

Comment: I actually ended up doing a pleasant mix of both answers. I created a ScheduleAdjuster class that contains a PaymentModel class. The payment model is very similar to yours with additional functions to make it look a bit more "fluent". My adjuster has two private functions (Adjust and Replace) and then a public AdjustSchedules function that just calls one or the other. Thank you both!

Answer (score 1):

Note: this post is after the OP selected the preferred answer.

> It's so large because I'm having troubles reducing the function into smaller parts without either having to pass many parameters along or recalculate some things.

[@NikitaBrizhak](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/100523/scheduled-adjustable-payments#comment183700_100561) is absolutely right on.

It's the lack of class design that is the problem. Classes that exhibit the **S**ingle **R**esponsibility **P**rinciple will *naturally* distribute the busy-ness and complexity such that most of your existing function will disappear - the details will be in appropriate classes.

I imagine you're too far along with this project to re-work design. However, thoughtful refactoring the function itself as suggested by the (currently) 2 answers will help if you want to tackle the design.

NOTE: these are inspirational examples. Don't cut-n-paste this stuff into your code!

---

### There and Back Again - a Refactor tale

The basic game plan is to keep client code from having to know class details to do things. You want the client to "ask" an object to do something, not do it for the object.

These first few ideas should be direct substitutions into your existing function - meaning that the function will not break (this is the definition of "refactor").

Once the classes have some functionality you can pull out snippets of processing from the function.

---

#### Version Control CYA

STOP! Do this first. Hear me know and believe me later.

Put version control software on your computer; Subversion Mercurial, GIT... whichever you prefer. I use Mercurial.

I have version control on my computer even though we use version control as team. I can experiment at will, recover, and never affect the o-fishal code base.

#### Basic Class Functionality

Implement `IComparable` Then this:

```
_allHeaderSchedules.OrderBy(x => x.OccurrenceNbr); // doing it for the class
```

will become this:

```
_allHeaderSchedules.Sort(); // asking the class to sort itself.
```

---

Override `Equals` (and `GetHashCode` at the same time). This will allow you to `Find()` any given payment object w/in a collection; or prevent duplicate entries -

```
if(myCollection.Contains(thisPayment))
```

---

#### Collection functionality

```
 allSchedules.Where(x => x.PaymentDate >= adjEffectiveStart && x.PaymentDate < adjEffectiveEnd).OrderBy(x => x.OccurrenceNbr).ToList();
```

becomes

```
allSchedules.InAdjustmentRange(adjEffectiveStart, adjEffectiveEnd);
```

Once you get some functionality into your `collection` many interim code lines in the existing function go away too.

---

implement `IComparable` for the collection to make it sort by date order.

```
allSchedules.Sort();
```

---

#### Next Level Refactoring

The previous refactoring make the next step possible. You must have basic class functionality first or you will be hacking at code all over the place all at once and you'll break everything.

#### DateRange Class ?

The initial refactorings has me using start/end date pairs, especially for method parameters. Maybe there should be a simple class for this

#### Extract Actual Loan Processing

THIS:

```
  foreach (RecurringSchedule schedule in schedulesAfterAdj)
    {
        remainingBalance -= schedule.PaymentAmount;

        schedule.RemainingBalance = remainingBalance;

        // THRESHHOLD: If the balance after the next payment is under
        // the threshhold then add it to the current payment and let
        // remaining payment schedules be a payment of nothing.
        if (remainingBalance != 0 && schedule.AdjustForThreshhold(decreaseAmountBy))
        {
            paymentAmount = 0;
            remainingBalance = 0;
            decreaseAmountBy = 0;
        }

        schedules.Add(schedule);
    }
}
```

Could Become something like THIS:

```
 remaingBalance = allSchedules.InAdjustmentRange(dateRangeObject).CalculateBalance();
```

Wow. Just a hint at the power of good class design.

---

#### Every class does its part

The "payment"/"paymentTransaction" class should be calculating its own balance, and the scheduleCollection should leverage this:

```
public class scheduleCollection {
    public decimal CalculateBalance() {
        decimal currentBalance = loanHeaderObject.LoanAmount;
        this.Sort();  // in date order, I assume

        foreach(var payment in this) 
            currentBalance = payment.CalcualteBalance(currentBalance);

        return currentBalance;        
    }
}
```